# Как сделать распознавание речи на WPF/C# приложении?

Tags: c#, wpf, распознавание-речи

Например кнопка "Начать" -> нажимаешь-воспринимается звук- 
кнопка "Остановить"(она же)-> 
отправляется звуковой файл на google сервер-> получаю ответ.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: Если интересно и еще актуально напиши мне на майл martin_47@mail.ru  я реализовал подобное

Answer (score 7):

Конкретно WPF тебе, кроме интерфейса, врядли, чем-то поможет. Т.о. задача распадается на 2.

1. Записать аудио. Наверняка, поможет проект [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/). NAudio это открытый проект - Api для .NET для работы с аудио
2. Конвертировать в нужный аудио формат и разпознать при помощи Google Voice. С позволения авторов, направляю [на эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117234/).

Удачи!

Answer (score 3):

Советую посмотреть на **SpeechKit Cloud** от Яндекс.
https://tech.yandex.ru/speechkit/cloud/
К сожалению, готовой библиотеки для C# не существует.